# "Confirmation parents' meeting" or "confirmation parents meeting"?

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives, apostrophe

If a meeting is for a group of parents run by a Church, for example, would it
be "Confirmation parents' meeting" or "Confirmation parents meeting"?

Comment: Does the meeting belong to the parents in some sense, or is it merely composed of them?

Comment: its composed of them with a non-parent leader

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you want to be very correct, use the apostrophe.  But if you get the vibes that the apostrophe might put some of the parents off, it's okay to leave it out.